# Updating ObservableCollection does not properly update ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a ListView in XAML that is bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel. Upon initialization or OnAppearing() the ListView items are displayed perfectly.

However, when I try to update the ListView items from within the page (through ViewModel) the items are updated but the old items are still there.

Basically, the new items are added to the ListView but below the items that were in the ObservableCollection before. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and I think I have done everything correct (although clearly not).

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've tried Clear() on the Collection but to no avail (same outcome).

BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
                return;

            backingField = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView       IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoadingTable, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingTable, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LeagueStandings}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeam, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
                        RowHeight="60"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                        SeparatorColor="{DynamicResource accentColor}">
```

Page.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            ViewModel.LoadLeagueStandingsCommand.Execute(_divisionId);
            ViewModel.LoadPickerItemsCommand.Execute(null);
        }
```

ViewModel Initialization:

```
private ObservableCollection<Standing> _leagueStandings;
        public ObservableCollection<Standing> LeagueStandings
        {
            get { return _leagueStandings ?? (_leagueStandings = new ObservableCollection<Standing>()); }
            set { SetValue(ref _leagueStandings, value); }
        }
```

ViewModel Methods:

```
private async Task LoadLeagueStandings(string divId)
        {

            if (_hasLoadedStandings)
                return;

            if (IsLoadingTable)
                return;

            _hasLoadedStandings = true;

            _divisionId = divId;

            try
            {
                IsLoadingTable = true;
                await _pageService.DisplayAlert("loading Selected", _divisionId, "ok");
                var v = await GetLeagueTableAsync(_htmlParser, _divisionId);

                LeagueStandings = new ObservableCollection<Standing>(v);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception caught in DivisionsViewModel.cs.(LoadLeagueStandings).");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsLoadingTable = false;
            }

        }
```

ViewModel method called when Picker item changes:

```
private async Task SelectItem(string item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            SelectedItem = null;

            var id = await _divisionFinder.GetDivisionIdAsync(item);

            var v = await GetLeagueTableAsync(_htmlParser, id);

            LeagueStandings = new ObservableCollection<Standing>(v);
        }
```

Edit* - Picture of outcome. First collection ends at number 5 and new collections appends to end of listview starting at 1 again.

[ListView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cApbZ.png)

Edit 2:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Standing>> GetLeagueTableAsync(string divisionId)
    {
        // todo: get division Id from picker

        string address = "";
        if (IsOnline)
        {
            if (divisionId != "")
                address = $"{BaseUrls.LeagueStandings}{divisionId}";

            try
            {
                var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
                var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
                var cSelector = "table[class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered'] tr";

                var table = document.QuerySelectorAll(cSelector).Skip(1);

                int count = 0;
                foreach (var c in table)
                {
                    var cells = c.QuerySelectorAll("td").ToArray();

                    _leagueStandings.Add(new Standing(++count, cells[0].TextContent.Trim(), cells[1].TextContent.Trim(),
                                                               cells[2].TextContent.Trim(), cells[3].TextContent.Trim(),
                                                               cells[4].TextContent.Trim(), cells[5].TextContent.Trim(),
                                                               cells[6].TextContent.Trim(), cells[7].TextContent.Trim()));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"\n\n Exception caught LoadingLeagueTable - {e} \n\n");
            }
        }
        return _leagueStandings;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're not adding neither removing items, and you're replacing the reference you need to raise the event telling that the view has changed. Instead of your code, replace it by this

```
    private ObservableCollection<Standing> _leagueStandings;
    public ObservableCollection<Standing> LeagueStandings
    {
        get { return _leagueStandings; }
        set { 
              _leagueStandings = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("LeagueStandings"); 
            }
    }
```

Also for future references, `ObservableCollection` already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you don't need to `SetValue(x)`..

Comment: I have done as above but still getting the same outcome.

`private ObservableCollection<Standing> _leagueStandings;
        public ObservableCollection<Standing> LeagueStandings
        {
            get { return _leagueStandings; }
            set
            {
                _leagueStandings = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LeagueStandings");
            }
        }`

I will edit post to show the outcome

Comment: Can you please try to break it in `ObservableCollection<Standing> temp = new ObservableCollection<Standing>(v); LeagueStandings = temp;`

Comment: OK, I've just done this. At the breakpoint, LeagueStandings's Count is 8 (correct) and temp's count is 13 (should be 5) so it looks like the problem is maybe not with the observablecollection but rather my async call? Temp's count should be 5 but seems to be 8 (previous count) + 5 (new count). Any ideas??

Comment: `GetLeagueTableAsync` Probably has to do with this line.. Dont know what are you doing in there

Comment: I have added the method into my post. If you have a second, please help me out! Appreciate your efforts!

Comment: _leagueStandings is of type List<Standing>

Comment: I have just answered my own question, now that I look at my strange declaration of _leagueStandings. For some odd reason I was initializing it outside of the GetTable method.

Comment: Apologies for the waste of time Greggz. But you taught me something about ObservableCollections and thanks to you I found the issue. Big thanks!

Comment: Oh okay! No problem ;)