# Picker not updating when ItemsSource changed

Tags: xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a Xamarin.Forms (3.2, latest version) `Picker` implemented as

```
<Picker x:Name="ClassSelector"
            Title="Select Class"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Classrooms}"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ClassroomName}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClassroom}">
</Picker>
```

The BindingContext is this ViewModel:

```
public class ClassroomsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }

  public ClassroomsViewModel()
  {
     Classrooms = new ObservableCollection<Classroom>(_ClassroomsRepository.GetAll());
  }
}
```

Now, when I add a classroom in the `ViewModel`, the Picker dutifully adds the item to its list:

```
 Classrooms.Add(new Classroom() { ClassroomName = "test" });   // this works fine
```

But if I *modify* a classroom, the `Picker` doesn't update its items list:

```
Classrooms[0].ClassroomName = "test";  // this doesn't have an effect,
                                       // although the value is set
                                       // in the ObservableCollection
```

I've also tried explicitly calling:

```
    OnPropertyChanged();  // nothing
    OnPropertyChanged("Classrooms"); // nope
```

If it's important, `Classroom` does derive from `ObservableObject`:

```
public class Classroom : ObservableObject
{
   private string classroomName;

   public string ClassroomName { get => classroomName; set => SetProperty(ref classroomName, value); }
}
```

#### Edit, in which I clarify that this *isn't* a collection-replacement issue:

Note that I am *not* replacing the `Classrooms` collection with a new ObservableCollection -- as happens in other posts that may appear similar to my issue. I am simply *modifying* one of the collection's members. When this collection is bound to a different control (like a `ListView`), it behaves exactly as expected -- the `ListView` updates to reflect the new `ClassroomName`.

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating ObservableCollection does not properly update ListView in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137114/updating-observablecollection-does-not-properly-update-listview-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, when we use bindings, we expect the target (a picker-item) to keep itself in sync with the binding source (in this case a `Classroom` object) - so, your code, by design, is correct.

However, after digging into `Picker` source code in XF github - it looks like it unsubscribes from binding/property-changes after pulling the first value from `Binding`. [Here you can see the explicit call to `UnApply()`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Picker.cs#L136) to the binding, and subsequently to the binding-expression for picker-item display name.

Invoking `OnPropertyChanged("Classrooms");` on `CustomerViewModel` (not on `Customer`) should technically work. Or, you can try removing the modified `Customer` object from the collection, and re-adding at same index to fix this issue. Both of these actions will trigger the [`ResetItems()`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Picker.cs#L213) - which in turn should trigger the refresh for [picker-item's display name](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Picker.cs#L219).

Comment: Thank you for this. Using `OnPropertyChanged("Classrooms")` on the view model does not seem to trigger `ResetItems()`, but the remove/replace item workaround takes care of it.

Comment: I assume that the `UnApply()` call is how Xamarin controls make themselves `OneWay` bound? Which would imply that the Picker's ItemsSource binding is *only* `OneWay`. This isn't noted in the documentation, so I'm going to file it as a bug report (or, at the very least, a need for an update to the documentation).

Comment: Issue added to Xamarin.Forms : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4077

Comment: @GrahamCharles: It seems UnApply pretty much disconnects the binding connection between source and target. That is different from `OneWay` mode, where you expect the change notification to always flow from source to target. Were you talking about `OneTime` mode?

Comment: Having said that, thank you for reporting the issue. This should be documented at-least.

Comment: Oh right, `OneTime` makes more sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, setting the source to null and then resetting it works for me:

```
var items = picker.ItemsSource as List<string>;
items.Add("item");
picker.ItemsSource = null;
picker.ItemsSource = items;
```